# How to query Sybase db with PHP

Tags: php, sybase

I have been looking everywhere for a way to query our Sybase db with php. I am able to query it with a database visualizing tool without issue, but PHP is giving me lots of problems.

PHP version is 5.5.31
I've tried using sybase_connect and other methods but now I'm reading that I may need a driver to even use sybase_connect?

sybase_connect('my_db_name', 'Username', 'password');

I've tried using PDO with a driver I found but have no idea how to use the driver.

Would like to connect to our Sybase database and query it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "lots of problems"?

Comment: which sybase version are you using

Comment: Lately it has been undefined function sql_connect() and I have no idea how to fix that

Comment: I am unsure of the Sybase version since it is on the server and not my local machine

Comment: can you check if my response works please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had some problems when I tried to do this.

The solution with:

```
PHP: v5.6.36
Sybase: SQL Anywhere 12.0.1.4134
```

first you have to download the specific DLL, available from the site, for your specific php version. You can find the PHP modules here: [sybase php module](https://archive.sap.com/documents/docs/DOC-40537)

second, you copy the files to your PHP extension dir. You can find the specific folder, using the phpinfo() and looking for: extension_dir.

after copy the files, add to your php.ini the extension, like this:

```
extension=php-5.6.0_sqlanywhere.dll
```

check if sqlanywhere is available at your phpinfo() page. Just search and find.

if it's available, you have everything you need.

For last, just try the connection like this:

if the connection is on localhost:

```
sasql_connect("uid=dba;pwd=sql")
```

since you mentioned that the database is in the server, try this:

```
sasql_connect("UID=dba;PWD=sql;SERVER=test_12")
```

You can find some good examples with this [here](https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/-/sasql_connect/php-sasql_connect-function-examples.html)

Comment: That works !! Thank you so much, this issue was really frustrating